# Why do we need to use toString method with StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

What is the difference between line 6 and line 8?

They both print the same string. Why do we need to use toString with StringBuilder?

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("hello");   // Line 1
System.out.println(s);                          // Line 2

s.append("hi");                                 // Line 3
System.out.println(s);                          // Line 4

s.append("okk");                                // Line 5
System.out.println(s);                          // Line 6

s.toString();                                   // Line 7
System.out.println(s);                          // Line 8
```

Comment: The line before the last is useless, you should assign that back to a string.So basically line 6 and 8 are doing exactly the same. If you want to test you theory, do System.out.println(s.ToString()).

That being said, the println function is doing it for you in both cases, so basically, println behind the scenes, takes the value of your string builder which is a string and print it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing different between line 6 and line 8.

[PrintStream.println(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) calls [string.valueOf(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) which calls the object's `toString()` method, and that gets printed.

`System.out.println(s)` and `System.out.println(s.toString())` have the same output (unless `s` is `null`, in which case the latter throws an exception).

The reason you call `s.toString()` directly is to get the current "built" value from the StringBuilder as a `string` so you can pass it on to other code which expects a `string`.  If the code you want to call takes a `StringBuilder` you could just pass `s`, but then the called code has the ability to modify your value (they can't with `string` because it is an immutable data type).

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println can print out arrays of chars (line6)
s.toString() is used to actually place the stringbuilder contents into a string. in your code you are not setting it to a string variable so nothing will happen... so on line8 the array of chars is printed again from the contents of your string builder.

if you add
string str = s.toString();
System.out.println(str);

then the string will print the string variable made from the stringbuilder.

Comment: Line 6 doesn't print an array of characters.  It prints an object... by calling its toString method.

Comment: Yes, I had that in my head, and then read you post cheers for the reminder. I upvoted you answer too, as it's better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder needs toString() to convert the mutable sequence of characters to String.

So technically, to return a StringBuilder obj from a method returning String, you have to convert the StringBuilder to String using toString().

You can also sysout a StringBuilder obj without the method toString() to get the values directly